# jetpack compose lazy custom layout

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I tried to develop a simple custom layout just like the documentation

```
@Composable
fun MyBasicColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        // Don't constrain child views further, measure them with given constraints
        // List of measured children
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
        // Measure each children
        measurable.measure(constraints)
        }

        // Set the size of the layout as big as it can
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
        // Track the y co-ord we have placed children up to
        var yPosition = 0

        // Place children in the parent layout
        placeables.forEach { placeable ->
            // Position item on the screen
            placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)

            // Record the y co-ord placed up to
            yPosition += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine when I know exact number of items
but what about lazy items?
there is nothing in documentation about how can I develop a `LazyCustomLayout`

Comment: You can use `LazyLayout`, but it was only introduced in the latest **1.2.0-alpha08**, that's why there's no documentation so far, you have to explore the API and check out how `LazyColumn` is using it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't exactly have to know how many items are in the `Layout`, since even for dynamic lists, there's always a 'current number of items' which can be computed. Let's say you download a list of texts from a server, and then intend to use this `Layout` to render those. Even in that case, while the server may vary the length of the list, i.e., the list is dynamic in size, you would presumably have a `LiveData` object keeping track of the list items. From there, you can easily use the `collectAsState()` method inside a `Composable`, or the `observeAsState()` method tied to a `LifecycleOwner` to convert it into the Compose-compatible `MutableState<T>` variable. Hence, whenever the `LiveData` notifies a new value (addition, or deletion), the `MutableState<T>` variable will also be updated to reflect those values. This, you can use inside the said `Layout`, which is also a `Composable` and hence, will update along-side the server-values, in real-time.

The thing is, no matter how you get your list, in order to show it on-screen, or use it anywhere in your app, you would always have a list object, which can be exploited using `Compose`'s declarative and reactive nature.

Comment: it is correct but every time state changes all of the childs of my layout are gonna rerender and this is a bad experience for user

Comment: Then unless a lazy layout is released, there doesn't seem to be much you can do.